# How to create a .txt file with Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

How to create a text file with Ballerina programming language? Defining the file name and path where the file should be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ballerina/io`](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/io.html) package to create files.

Here is an example using `io:ByteChannel`

```
import ballerina/io;

function main (string... args) {
    io:ByteChannel byteChannel = io:openFile("/absolute/path/to/file.txt", io:WRITE); // If the file does not exist it will be created
    string someContent = "some content";
    byte[] content = someContent.toByteArray("UTF-8");
    var writeResult = byteChannel.write(content, 0);
    io:print(writeResult);
}
```

Instead of the absolute path you can supply a relative path. In that case the txt file will be created in a location relative to where you run ballerina from.

Comment: That was it, thank you!